# Jax RS PUT method - junit test

Tags: java, junit

I have 3 methods below.  The first one calls the second one and the second one calls the third. The junit test fails because all the methods are 'void', and I used an object to test junit.

```
public class Ids
    {

    @PUT

    @Path("/{otherId}")

    @Produces("application/xml")

//First method:

    public Response putTag
                (
                        @Context SecurityContext context
                        , @Context HttpServletRequest req
                        , @Context HttpServletResponse resp
                        , @PathParam("otherId") String otherId
                        , @FormParam("userId") String userId
                ) {

            Map<String, String> obj = new Hashtable<String, String>();

            obj.put("userId", userId);
            obj.put("otherId", otherId);

            putTagMethod(obj);
            return ResponseBuilder.buildResponse("Inserted tag records", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);    
        }
```

//Second Method

```
public void putTagMethod(Map<String, String> obj) {
        String userId = obj.get("userId");
        String entryId = obj.get("otherId");
        try {
            updateTag(userId, otherId);

        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("java.sql.SQLException: ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
```

//Third Method

```
public static void updateTag(String userId, String otherId) throws PersistenceException,  {
        if (...some condition) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("blah blah blah");
        }

        SpecialData data = null;
        //Update if found, else insert
        if (dataList != null && dataList.size() > 0) {
            data = dataList.get(0);
            update(userId, otherId);
        } else {
            insert(userId, otherId);
}
```

How do I write a Junit test to test 'Response putTag' method?
I wrote this (below) junit, but it gives error (

```
@Test

public void testPutTag() throws Exception
{
    Ids tags = new Ids();
    Map<String,String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String xml = tags.putTag(obj);
    assertTrue("PUT", xml.equals(
        "<result>insert</result>"));
}
```

I'm getting error:

```
Incompatible types
required: Map<String, String>
found: void
```

problem is I need to assign 'xml' to a return type but all my methods are void.

How do I solve this?

Anyone please advise...

Comment: static method to update?

Comment: Do you have any method like `getTag` which does opposite of `PUT`? you can use it before and after calling `putTag` to test whether the values indeed updated.

Comment: Yes, the static method (UpdateTag) is the one that does the insert or update if I can understand you correctly.

Comment: @user3351592 The code which you gave is not the reason for errir

Comment: Yes, I do have getTag as well which I did not paste here.  Trying to be specific.

Comment: It's the junit that's not compiling